# Sagemaker Studio notebook - no module named 'tensorflow' when chosen image type "Tensorflow 2.6 Python 3.8 GPU optimized"

Tags: tensorflow, amazon-sagemaker

I have created a simple notebook on SageMaker Studio using the Image "Tensorflow 2.6 Python 3.8 GPU optimized". But when I try to run simple statement viz. "import tensorflow", I am getting the error "no module named 'tensorflow'".

I tried to install 'tensorflow' package using pip from the terminal attached to the image. But it shows the message "requirement already satisfied".

Am I missing anything here? Please help.

Thanks in advance,
Surya Praveen

Comment: try tensorflow-gpu

Comment: Create virtual environment, activate it and install tensorflow. `pip install tensorflow`. Thanks!

Comment: The kernel claims to have Tensorflow -- and other Data Science tools -- already loaded. But I also get the same error. It's ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

I posted the same question in AWS forum "re:Post" and I got following answer.

The service team are aware of this issue and are actively working on a fix.
Meanwhile, you can try the following as workaround

1. Open a notebook using a Tensorflow 2.6 Python 3.8 kernel
2. Execute the following line in a notebook cell:

   !sed -i 's|^ *"python",| "/usr/local/bin/python",|g' /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3/kernel.json
3. Stop the kernel
4. Re-attach the kernel to your notebook.

This actually worked for me.